# How to store check box values using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple checkboxes. I have stored the checkbox values to the local storage, enabling the user to refresh the page and still have the checked or unchecked checkboxes displayed.  Now I need to save the check box value as a url parameter, so that the page can be sent as a link retaining all the unchecked or checked values. Code below:

HTML: (check boxes)

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox" id="like">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox" id="like1">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox" id="like2">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox" id="like2">
```

**Update**: please note I'm using a tabbed navigation menu and have added tab hash to url. Therefore a url will already look something like: *[www.example.com/index.html#home](http://www.example.com/index.html#home)*

Comment: Please post your code what you already have tried!

Comment: You may be looking for [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34878885/4763793

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) but you have to change the `name` atrribute's values.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  alert($('input').serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox1" id="like">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox2" id="like1">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox3" id="like2">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox4" id="like2">
<button>getUrl</button>
```

The next step is to get the values from the QueryString and set the `checkboxes`.

It's should looks like this:

```
$.each(location.search.replace('?', '').split('&'), function(i, seg) {
   $('[name=' + seg.split('=')[0] + ']').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/hecora/edit?html,js

**Update**

You can do "auto saving" when the user check/uncheck the checkboxes using `hash` or do `pushState` and add the params to the url (That's good in case from some reason you can't use the `hash` for this). Of course you need to check the [browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate) first.

Example (of `pushState`):

```js
var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.change(function() {
  var ser = '?' + checkboxes.serialize();
  history.pushState(null, null, ser);
});

$.each(location.search.replace('?', '').split('&'), function(i, seg) {
  $('[name=' + seg.split('=')[0] + ']').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox1" id="like">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox2" id="like1">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox3" id="like2">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox4" id="like2">
```

http://jsbin.com/nofoto/edit?html,js

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. it doesn't update the url. or do you have to update it manually?

Comment: Strange, no error on console. but doesn't seem to saving to the url.

Comment: `saving to the url` save where? The url (relative of course) is shown in the alert message.  In the bin I did the redirect and you can see that after the redirect, the state of the checkboxes "saved"

Comment: in the search, for example www.example.com/index.html#homelikebox1=onlikebox2=on ect. . .

Comment: No I didn't store it in the `hash`. it's just convert it to a URL format. You can do with this whatever you want: Add it to the `hash` or as QueryString. The second script collect the data from the QueryString.

Comment: Ok got the theory of it. but I really wouldn't know how to add it to the hash or as QueryString.

Comment: If it's not too much, would you mind showing me?  @Mosh Feu

Comment: It's not hard at all. It was there all the time in the bin in the of the answer. This is the result http://output.jsbin.com/hecora

Comment: yeah I saw that. been trying to understand it. tried removing the alert. and editing it.

Comment: But it didn't really work as i'm not too sure what i'm editing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101153/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-about-leros).

Comment: Works for me.. http://jsbin.com/nofoto/edit?html,js and the result: http://output.jsbin.com/nofoto?likebox1=on&likebox2=on&likebox5=on&likebox6=on&likebox7=on&likebox8=on&likebox9=on&likebox10=on&likebox11=on&likebox12=on&likebox13=on&likebox14=on&likebox16=on

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307908/2856218) answer:

```
var checkArray = new Array(); 
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) checkArray.push(this.id)
});
var urlParameter = checkArray.join('&')
```

This would generate a string, containing the ids of all checked checkboxes. It works by iterating over all checkboxes on the page, saving the ids and then concatenating them with '&'. On loading the page you only have read the url parameters (e.g. http://website.com?checkbox1&checkbox2 would check checkbox1 and checkbox2) and check the boxes like you did with the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

should use

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='likebox']").each( ...
```