# Custom select box onChange doesn't work

Tags: jquery, select

I am using custom select box script, but the problem is that when I change value, it does nothing (like in demo).

```js
// Iterate over each select element
$('select').each(function () {

  // Cache the number of options
  var $this = $(this),
      numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  // Hides the select element
  $this.addClass('s-hidden');

  // Wrap the select element in a div
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

  // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
  $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

  // Cache the styled div
  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

  // Show the first select option in the styled div
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

  // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  // Cache the list items
  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)
  $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.styledSelect.active').each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
  });

  // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
  // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
  $listItems.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
  });

  // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
  $(document).click(function () {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;
  background-color:white;
}
.s-hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.select {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font:normal 11px/22px Arial, Sans-Serif;
  color:black;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.styledSelect {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:white;
  padding:0 10px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.styledSelect:after {
  content:"";
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border:5px solid transparent;
  border-color:black transparent transparent transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:9px;
  right:6px;
}
.styledSelect:active, .styledSelect.active {
  background-color:#eee;
}
.options {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:999;
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 0;
  list-style:none;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:white;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.options li {
  padding:0 6px;
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 10px;
}
.options li:hover {
  background-color:#39f;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectbox1" onchange="alert('change')">
  <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>
  <option value="aye">Aye</option>
  <option value="eh">Eh</option>
  <option value="ooh">Ooh</option>
  <option value="whoop">Whoop</option>
</select>
<select id="selectbox2">
  <option value="">Month&hellip;</option>
  <option value="january">January</option>
  <option value="february">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
  <option value="april">April</option>
  <option value="may">May</option>
  <option value="june">June</option>
  <option value="july">July</option>
  <option value="august">August</option>
  <option value="september">September</option>
  <option value="october">October</option>
  <option value="november">November</option>
  <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/47

Comment: so what do you expect when you change value?

Comment: I expect onChange event to start working. There is no onChange added to select box in demo, but even if I do, there is no effect. Probably I am missing something in jquery script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the `change` event after the selection like this:

```
$this.trigger('change');
```

**Working demo:**

```js
// Iterate over each select element
$('select').each(function () {

  // Cache the number of options
  var $this = $(this),
      numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  // Hides the select element
  $this.addClass('s-hidden');

  // Wrap the select element in a div
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

  // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
  $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

  // Cache the styled div
  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

  // Show the first select option in the styled div
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

  // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  // Cache the list items
  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)
  $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.styledSelect.active').each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
  });

  // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
  // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
  $listItems.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    $this.trigger('change');
    /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
  });

  // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
  $(document).click(function () {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;
  background-color:white;
}
.s-hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.select {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font:normal 11px/22px Arial, Sans-Serif;
  color:black;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.styledSelect {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:white;
  padding:0 10px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.styledSelect:after {
  content:"";
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border:5px solid transparent;
  border-color:black transparent transparent transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:9px;
  right:6px;
}
.styledSelect:active, .styledSelect.active {
  background-color:#eee;
}
.options {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:999;
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 0;
  list-style:none;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:white;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.options li {
  padding:0 6px;
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 10px;
}
.options li:hover {
  background-color:#39f;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectbox1" onchange="alert(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>
  <option value="aye">Aye</option>
  <option value="eh">Eh</option>
  <option value="ooh">Ooh</option>
  <option value="whoop">Whoop</option>
</select>
<select id="selectbox2" onchange="alert(this.value)">
  <option value="">Month&hellip;</option>
  <option value="january">January</option>
  <option value="february">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
  <option value="april">April</option>
  <option value="may">May</option>
  <option value="june">June</option>
  <option value="july">July</option>
  <option value="august">August</option>
  <option value="september">September</option>
  <option value="october">October</option>
  <option value="november">November</option>
  <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: one more question, after page refreshes, value changes to the first one, how to keep selected value even after page refreshes?

Comment: You can store the values in the URL like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878569/how-to-store-check-box-values-using-javascript-or-jquery/34878797#34878797

Comment: how do i add / remove the options dynamically? i tried appending and rerun the function again but it doesnt work

Comment: @wsgg I'm not sure I understand. Can you create a [bin](https://jsbin.com) with your effort?