# Grapping the content of a custom select field onchange doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onchange

I have a form with a custom select dropdown-list. Don´t know how to get that selected content from the select into an alert-Box.

I tried:

```html
<body>
<div onchange="alert('Something important...');" id="Select" class="custom-select selectBoxKlasse Filter <?php echo $redTermin; ?>">
                          <select id="defaultSelect" name="terminselectAuto" class="alle_select select_Filter">
                            <option><?php echo $terminTitleB; ?></option>
                            <option>23. Dez. 2020</option>
                            <option>2. Jän. 2021</option>
                            <option>29. Feb. 2021</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>


<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" ></script><!--JQUERY-->
<script src="js/modernizr-custom.js" ></script><!--JQUERY-->
<script>


/*CUSTOM SELECT DROPDOWN LISTE BEGIN*/



    //document.querySelector('.custom-select-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //this.querySelector('.custom-select').classList.toggle('open');
    //})
    for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom-option")) {
        option.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!this.classList.contains('selected')) {
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.custom-option.selected').classList.remove('selected');
                this.classList.add('selected');
                this.closest('.custom-select').querySelector('.custom-select__trigger span').textContent = this.textContent;
            }
        })
    }


    for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select-wrapper")) {
      dropdown.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.querySelector('.custom-select').classList.toggle('open');
      })
    }


    //window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      //  const select = document.querySelector('.custom-select')
  //      if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
    //        select.classList.remove('open');
    //    }
  //  });
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      for (const select of document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select')) {
          if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
              select.classList.remove('open');
          }
      }
  });


    var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
    /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
    l = x.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      ll = selElmnt.length;
      /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
      a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
      x[i].appendChild(a);
      /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
      b = document.createElement("DIV");
      b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
      for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
        /*for each option in the original select element,
        create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
        c = document.createElement("DIV");
        c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
        c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
            and the selected item:*/
            var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
            s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            sl = s.length;
            h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
            for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
              if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                s.selectedIndex = i;
                h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                yl = y.length;
                for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
                  y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                }
                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                break;
              }
            }
            h.click();
        });
        b.appendChild(c);
      }
      x[i].appendChild(b);
      a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
          and open/close the current select box:*/
          e.stopPropagation();
          closeAllSelect(this);
          this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
          this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
        });
    }
    function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
      /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
      except the current select box:*/
      var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
      y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
      xl = x.length;
      yl = y.length;
      for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
        if (elmnt == y[i]) {
          arrNo.push(i)
        } else {
          y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
        if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
          x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
        }
      }
    }
    /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
    then close all select boxes:*/

</script>
</body>
```

As you can see in my cody, I´m not the best in javascript, so my attempts to solve this problem failed horribly and there is no hope at all to get this done without any help from outside. :) Hopefully there is somebody out there, who wants to help me.

I forgot top post a part of the javascript I use:

´´´
/*Klassenfilter BEGIN*/

```
        /*make this when termin is preselected onload*/
        $( document ).ready(function() {

          //Grap the url-proberty terminKlasse
          let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          searchParams.has('terminKlasse'); // true
          let param = searchParams.get('terminKlasse');

          //create the variables
          var termin_klasse = param;
          var alle_select_wrap = $(".selectBoxKlasse");
          var alle_sel = $(".alle_select");
          var clicked_Filt = termin_klasse;
          clicked_Filter_Wrap = "." + clicked_Filt;
          clicked_Filter_sel = ".select_" + clicked_Filt;

          //display and disable Select-Boxes
          $(clicked_Filter_Wrap).css( "display", "block" );
          $(clicked_Filter_sel).prop( "disabled", false );

          if(termin_klasse != null) {
            $("#Select").css( "display", "none" );
            $("#defaultSelect").prop( "disabled", "true" );
          }

        });




        /*make this when FilterBTNS are clicked*/
        $(".filter").click(function() {

            //create the variables
            var alle_select_wrapper = $(".selectBoxKlasse");
            var alle_select = $(".alle_select");
            var alle_Class = $(".checkClass");
            var clicked_Filter = $(this).attr('id');
            clicked_Filter_Wrapper = "." + clicked_Filter;
            clicked_Filter_select = ".select_" + clicked_Filter;
            clicked_Filter_class = ".class_" + clicked_Filter;

            //display and disable Select-Boxes and Checkboxes
            alle_select_wrapper.css( "display", "none" );
            $(clicked_Filter_Wrapper).css( "display", "block" );
            alle_select.prop( "disabled", true );
            $(clicked_Filter_select).prop( "disabled", false );
            alle_Class.prop( "checked", false);
            $(clicked_Filter_class).prop( "checked", true);

            //highlight and unlight filter Tabs when clicked
            var alle_filter_tabs = $(".filter");
            var clicked_Tab = $(this).attr('id');
            clicked_Tab =  "#" + clicked_Tab;

            alle_filter_tabs.css({ "background" : "#ededed", "color" : "#000" });
            $(clicked_Tab).css({ "background" : "#0066CC", "color" : "#FFF" });



        });
  /*Klassenfilter END*/
```

´´´

Maybe the failure is inside this part. Maybe my disabling the select box is faulty.

Comment: I found something like: You are just need to trigger the change event after the selection like this:

$this.trigger('change'); at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338663/custom-select-box-onchange-doesnt-work, but don´t know if this solution is working with my code and where to put it.

Comment: Remove the "onchnage" from "div" and use "onchange="alert(this.value)" in "select". Like below:
<select onchange="alert(this.value)" id="defaultSelect" name="terminselectAuto" class="alle_select select_Filter">

Comment: Use `onchange` inside select element not in div.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an eventlistener instead of the inline onclick()

Make an eventListener for for element with id *Select element*, listen for the change event then read out the property .value and alert it

```
document.getElementById('defaultSelect').addEventListener('change', function(){
alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<body>
<div id="Select" class="custom-select selectBoxKlasse Filter <?php echo $redTermin; ?>">
                          <select id="defaultSelect" name="terminselectAuto" class="alle_select select_Filter">
                            <option><?php echo $terminTitleB; ?></option>
                            <option>23. Dez. 2020</option>
                            <option>2. Jän. 2021</option>
                            <option>29. Feb. 2021</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>


<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" ></script><!--JQUERY-->
<script src="js/modernizr-custom.js" ></script><!--JQUERY-->
<script>

document.getElementById('defaultSelect').addEventListener('change', function(){
alert(this.value);
});

/*CUSTOM SELECT DROPDOWN LISTE BEGIN*/



    //document.querySelector('.custom-select-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //this.querySelector('.custom-select').classList.toggle('open');
    //})
    for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom-option")) {
        option.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!this.classList.contains('selected')) {
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.custom-option.selected').classList.remove('selected');
                this.classList.add('selected');
                this.closest('.custom-select').querySelector('.custom-select__trigger span').textContent = this.textContent;
            }
        })
    }


    for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select-wrapper")) {
      dropdown.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.querySelector('.custom-select').classList.toggle('open');
      })
    }


    //window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      //  const select = document.querySelector('.custom-select')
  //      if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
    //        select.classList.remove('open');
    //    }
  //  });
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      for (const select of document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select')) {
          if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
              select.classList.remove('open');
          }
      }
  });


    var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
    /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
    l = x.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      ll = selElmnt.length;
      /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
      a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
      x[i].appendChild(a);
      /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
      b = document.createElement("DIV");
      b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
      for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
        /*for each option in the original select element,
        create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
        c = document.createElement("DIV");
        c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
        c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
            and the selected item:*/
            var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
            s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            sl = s.length;
            h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
            for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
              if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                s.selectedIndex = i;
                h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                yl = y.length;
                for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
                  y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                }
                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                break;
              }
            }
            h.click();
        });
        b.appendChild(c);
      }
      x[i].appendChild(b);
      a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
          and open/close the current select box:*/
          e.stopPropagation();
          closeAllSelect(this);
          this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
          this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
        });
    }
    function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
      /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
      except the current select box:*/
      var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
      y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
      xl = x.length;
      yl = y.length;
      for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
        if (elmnt == y[i]) {
          arrNo.push(i)
        } else {
          y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
        if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
          x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
        }
      }
    }
    /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
    then close all select boxes:*/

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it´s not firing. It´s working when i use a normal select field but not when using  the custom select-field. I think the problem is, that the original select (which is overlayed by the custom select by javascript is deactivated?) Could it be?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but as you can see in the snippet above it is indeed firing.

Comment: I forgot the last javascript snippet to post. Maybe the failure is in this part. I have more select-tags in my html and need to disable all select-tags exept one to send only the values of one select-tag. I know, my code is crazy :) sorry for that

Comment: Instead of updating my answer you should update your question to give the information to the other people they come here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange` inside select element

```html
<div id="Select" class="custom-select selectBoxKlasse Filter">
                          <select onchange="alert(this.value)" id="defaultSelect" name="terminselectAuto" class="alle_select select_Filter">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>23. Dez. 2020</option>
                            <option>2. Jän. 2021</option>
                            <option>29. Feb. 2021</option>
                            <option>&nbsp;</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you for the ultrafast response. It tried your solution but it doesn´t work.